# SBS Active directory local administrator

Tags: active-directory, windows-sbs

I have SBS 2008 installed on the network. Every computer on network is joined to a domain.

I want to grant local admin privileges to one computer so that the computer will stay in the domain, but with local administrator privileges.

I probably have to do something in Active Directory. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to grant local administrative privledges on just one computer, doing so through Active Directory or Group Policy is going to be more trouble than it's worth. Just create the user manually on the computer (or select an existing one) and add them to the Administrators group. [How-To](http://www.howtogeek.com/79890/add-a-user-to-administrator-group/)

Comment: That is solution :)